# regular expressions on infinite input

Tags: c++, regex, sockets, c++11, infinite

I'd like to use regular expressions to parse data received from a socket.
I've written a custom socket iterator so i can pass the data to `std`'s regex functions.
Keep in mind that the data could theoretically never end, the socket doesn't close after the full request is sent as the client expects a response and possibly future communication.

Let's pretend we have a very simple protocol, a requests consists of either `START` or `STOP`.
The real protocol is of course a lot more complex but for the sake of example this will do.

```
// A simple regular expression to parse this could be defined like so:
static const std::regex re("^(START|STOP)");
// And parsed using:
std::regex_match(begin, end, result, re); // 1
// or using regex_search
std::regex_search(begin, end, result, re); // 2
```

Let's say the client sends the word `START`, waits 5 seconds, then sends another character, `X` for example. In this case method #1 will wait 5 seconds before returning false. Now pretend the client doesn't send anything after the original `START` message, method #1 will never return.
As for method #2: let's say your input is `XSTART`, the parser doesn't seem to understand that a valid match will never be found because the regex starts with `^`, and because the input is infinite it will never terminate either.
So in the end method #1 correctly identifies invalid requests while method #2 correctly identifies valid requests, but method #1 gets stuck in an infinite loop upon a valid request and method #2 gets stuck on an invalid request.

This [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

// stdin iterator that goes against all good
// programming practices for the sake of simplicity
class stdin_iter : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, char> {
    static std::vector<char> buf;
    size_t i;
public:
    stdin_iter() : i(SIZE_MAX) {}
    stdin_iter(size_t i) : i(i) {}
    bool operator==(const stdin_iter& o) const { return i == o.i; }
    bool operator!=(const stdin_iter& o) const { return i != o.i; }
    value_type operator*() const {
        while (i >= buf.size()) buf.push_back(getc(stdin));
        return buf[i];
    }
    stdin_iter& operator++() { i++; return *this; }
    stdin_iter operator++(int) { stdin_iter r = *this; i++; return r; }
    stdin_iter& operator--() { i--; return *this; }
    stdin_iter operator--(int) { stdin_iter r = *this; i--; return r; }
};
std::vector<char> stdin_iter::buf;

int main() {
    stdin_iter begin(0), end;
    std::regex re("^(START|STOP)");
    std::match_results<stdin_iter> result;

    //bool valid = std::regex_match(begin, end, result, re); // stuck on valid input
    //bool valid = std::regex_search(begin, end, result, re); // stuck on invalid input
    bool valid = std::regex_search(begin, end, result, re, std::regex_constants::match_continuous); // mostly works

    if (valid) printf("valid: %s\n", result[1].str().c_str());
    else printf("invalid\n");
}
```

One solution is to add an artificial end to the data after, for example, a second of inactivity. But this massively increases response time and just doesn't feel right.
Yet another solution is to write a custom regex parser, but it seems overkill to reinvent the wheel for a problem this simple.
Is there a better way to make this work?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you need. To match a string that is either `Start` or `Stop`, `"Start|Stop"` regex with `regex_match` will do.

Comment: No parser can take infinitely long input and be expected to terminate in finite time. You are probably better of resetting your state after a newline, since you are looking for occurrences at the beginning of a line.

Comment: @SamiHult Parsing infinitely long input is perfectly fine if the regular expression matches only a finite number of characters. I'm not looking to match occurrences at the beginning of a line, but rather at the beginning of the message.

Comment: Yes, if you can count on the algorithm to terminate (controlled input) or don't care about if it terminates or not. Your practical problem may be that `regex_search` will try to match all occurrences in your input, and for an eternal input that will not terminate. Have you tried with `match_any` flag?

Comment: `match_any` doesn't seem to help, but while looking through some of the other flags i found `match_continuous` which does exactly what i want.

Comment: There is no such thing as infinite input. It will end eventually. The question is, will you take control of that ending or will you let fate decide?

Comment: I'm not getting the infinite loop stuff though. An [MCVE] would really help to explain your problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The input could theoretically go on forever, though this is an invalid request a robust implementation should handle all cases. My question is more about determining if the input is valid even if you're not sure that you've received all of it, `STAX` *should* immediately be determined invalid without reading the rest of the input, and `START` *should* be considered valid without checking if there is another character after it causing it to be neither `START` nor `STOP`. Both of the above methods fail at least one of those cases.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, I suppose you could pass some iterators that represent a never-ending range. If you're doing that, that's one of the things I want to see in your [MCVE]. Note that this would not satisfy the definition of "range" (if `begin` will never reach `end`) and thus probably has UB anyway

Comment: That is indeed the custom iterator i'm talking about, though i can't think of an example that is Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable. It would consist of a buffered socket and an iterator over the buffered data, my implementation of this is over 300 lines.

Comment: Somehow you're going to have to find a way to minimise it. I don't quite follow how you could have been debugging the problem without having done so already

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've added a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I feel like i've really outdone myself with this one.

Comment: By the way, `std::istream_iterator` already exists

Comment: Use a single regex that matches all your scenario's. Put each in an alternation encased in a capture group. Only 1 group will match at a time which give's you the logic to tell what matched via iterator index.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `std::istream_iterator` is an InputIterator, regular expressions require a BidirectionalIterator.

Comment: @DutChen18 Oh, so they do. Well, that should already be a hint ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit a hint to what? My implementation works with `std::regex_constants::match_continuous`, so what's your point?

Comment: That `std::regex` is not intended to be coupled so tightly to an input stream. Note that your implementation will end up buffering the entire input data.

Comment: I had to `Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem.` for my Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, my actual implementation clears the buffer after the regex is matched. And to be honest i don't care what `std::regex` is *intended* to do, being able to parse requests using regular expressions results in clean code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `std::regex_constants::match_continuous` flag, Luke.